# Botón con icono (img) dentro no funciona en Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, google-chrome

Necesito arreglar un error o un comportamiento no deseado que sólo ocurre en Google Chrome, en el resto de navegadores funciona correctamente. En Chrome no me funciona hacer clic en la imagen interior del botón, en cambio, funciona al clicar en el botón pero fuera de la imagen interior.

El código del botón HTML devuelto por un script en **perl** es:

```
   print "document.write('<tbody class=\"no_ordenar\"><tr id=\"f0\"><td><button class=\"binsertar\" eb=0><img style=\"margin: 0 18px 0 18px\" src=\"imagenes/table_add.png\" alt=\"\"></button></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class=\"tdnotas\">Notas</td><td></td></tr></tbody>');\n";
```

El código **JavaScript** donde se cambia la imagen del icono es:

```
function clicBotonPapelera($target) {
if ( $target.attr('eb') == 0 ) {
    $target.find('img').attr('src','imagenes/papelera_r.png');
    $target.attr('eb', 1);
} else {
    $target.find('img').attr('src','imagenes/papelera_g.png');
    $target.attr('eb', 0);
}
}
```

y el código que ejecuta **perl** una vez clicado es:

```
function eliminarProveedoresBD() {
$("#proveliminados").dialog( "open" );
$("#reseliminacion").html("");

$(".bborrar").each( function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('eb') == 1 ) {
        var valor = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id").replace(/^f/,"");
        llamada = document.createElement('script');
        llamada.src = '/perl/inventario/eliminar_prov.pl?' + valor;
        document.body.appendChild(llamada);
        llamada.parentNode.removeChild(llamada);
    }
} )
}
```

Por lo que parece puede ser un problema con el valor de `eb` que hay en el botón

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer para que funcione en Chrome de forma correcta?

Comment: prueba a ponerle a la imagen en css: `img{pointer-events: none}`

Comment: Funciona!! Muchisimas gracias David, eres un crack!!!

Comment: Me alegro de que te funcione, lo paso a respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que al pulsar sobre la imagen no estás pulsando en el botón por que la imagen está por encima y se lleva el evento del click. Para solucionar esto puedes añadir a la imagen un simple css `pointer-events: none` para eliminar cualquier interacción del puntero del ratón con la imagen. Por tanto al pulsar en la imagen estarías pulsando en realidad en el objeto inmediatamente por debajo, que es el botón.